# Retrieve a List of All Checks for an Account using qbXML

Tags: qbxml

I'm working on a website for a client that integrates into QuickBook desktop.  I need to get a listing of all the checks for a specific account (ideally I would like all transactions for that account [regardless of their type] but if I have to get them one at a time that's fine).  When I send the following XML:

```
<ns1:sendRequestXMLResponse>
    <ns1:sendRequestXMLResult>
        <xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
        <qbxml version="12.0"?> 
        <QBXML>
            <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
                <CheckQueryRq>
                    <AccountFilter>
                    <ListID>800000F1-1362066981</ListID>
                    </AccountFilter>
                    <IncludeLineItems>true</IncludeLineItems>
                </CheckQueryRq>
            </QBXMLMsgsRq>
        </QBXML>
    </ns1:sendRequestXMLResult>
</ns1:sendRequestXMLResponse>
```

I receive the following error:

> <CheckQueryRs statusCode="1" statusSeverity="Info" statusMessage="A query request did not find a matching object in QuickBooks" />

If I go into QuickBooks I can see there are checks associated with the account so I'm not sure why this doesn't return a result.

**Update 1:** I rewrote this without the AccountFilter so it returned every check and I found checkes with the 800000F1-1362066981 account.  It's also 10 MB so it's really hard to work with.  :-)

Comment: What kind of account is it?    CheckQuery returns certain types of checks based on the supplied query criteria. Note that BillPaymentChecks, payroll checks, and liability checks are not returned.

Comment: This account is an OtherCurrentLiability but we also have Income and Expense accounts.